# Data Factory does not reuse nor disconnects from ODBC connection (Progress DB)

Tags: odbc, factory, openedge, progress-db, pooling

I have a ODBC connection to Progress DB, via licensed Progress ODBC connector, version 11.7 (PROGRESS_OE_11.7_WIN_64_SQLCLIENTACCESS). ADF uses this ODBC connection to do various tasks, like copy data or execute stored procedures on Progress DB. Everything is working, but the problem is that ADF does not release, nor reuse ODBC connection. In ADF, Until loop executes SQL command with Wait of 5 secs after each one. While viewing sessions in Progress DB we notice that ADF creates new session for each loop iteration (does not reuse previous one), and does not close the previous session. Old sessions timeout in about 100 seconds, but that is not fast enough, as it piles up to the limit.
I need a solution to either kill previous session or reuse previous session.

Tried SQL pooling options in ODBC Extended properties but it did not help. The properties that I tried:

`SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_POOLING=0`
`CPTimeout=0`
`Pooling=0`
`SQL_INFX_ATTR_CONNECTION_POOLING=0`
`CONNECTION_POOLING=0`

Answer (score 2):

Well that is awkward...I have been working with ODBC menu million times over past months, and missed this:

[[image: ODBC configuration]]